# json post request method

Tags: iphone, json

```
 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *encodedString = [jsonString base64EncodedString];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@wsName",baseUrl]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setValue:encodedString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense. You're creating JSON, base-64 encoding it (you never have to base-64 encode JSON; if you were really trying to encrypt it, you have to come up with something better), and setting the header `Data` with this, while simultaneously providing a `Content-Type` informing the server that the request was XML, even though it wasn't.

If the server was expecting JSON, you'd just send JSON:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:0 error:&error];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@wsName",baseUrl]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

If the server was expecting XML, you'd use the `text/xml` or `application/xml` setting for `Content-Type`, but you'd also (a) have to construct the XML content; and (b) supply that to `setHTTPBody`.

If you wanted to secure the request, you'd use `https://`.

Bottom line, you must confirm what precisely the server is looking for. Don't guess, but rather look at the server's source code or documentation or talk to the developers. But your client-side code sample is unlikely to work as it stands.